# Node.js Heroku Deployment - Fails To Exec Postinstall Script To Install Bower

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, bower

Deployment of my Node.js MEAN app to heroku fails with the following errors.  I can't figure out what is wrong with the bower install...

Here is the error message:

```
2606 info postinstall App@1.0.0
2607 verbose unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
2608 info App@1.0.0 Failed to exec postinstall script
2609 error App@1.0.0 postinstall: `./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install`
2609 error Exit status 1
2610 error Failed at the App@1.0.0 postinstall script.
2610 error This is most likely a problem with the App package,
2610 error not with npm itself.
2610 error Tell the author that this fails on your system:
2610 error     ./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app
```

Here is my Bower.json

```
    {
  "name": "mean",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "bootstrap": "*",
    "angular": "*",
    "angular-resource": "*",
    "angular-cookies": "*",
    "angular-ui-utils": "*",
    "angular-bootstrap": "*",
    "json3": "*",
    "jquery": "*",
    "angular-ui-router": "*",
    "angular-animate": "*",
    "move.js": "git://github.com/visionmedia/move.js.git#~0.3.3",
    "animate.css": "*",
    "ngAnimate-animate.css": "*",
    "angularLocalStorage": "~0.1.7",
    "jquery-nicescroll": "*"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.2.4"
  }
}
```

Here is my Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt",
    "test": "node node_modules/grunt-cli/bin/grunt test",
    "postinstall": "./node_modules/bower/bin/bower install"
},
```

Comment: Now days you don't need to specify a path to where bower is. This is sufficient: 
"postinstall" : " bower install"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I get this error a lot too. every third push to heroku fails because of bower postinstall.

While this is not a robust fix, and I don't fully understand why it helps! but this hepled me, so hopefully will help someone else.

Despite /lib folder is being added to .gitignore, force add it before deploying heroku

```
git add -f public/lib
git commit -m "force add bower libs"
git push heroku master
```

Comment: @JimHall it's directory where I told bower to install all libraries

Comment: This worked, but it smells like a hack.  Can anyone provide some detail? @ibeitia 's answer didn't work for me.

Comment: Did the trick, but what the hell is actually really going on?

Comment: So, maybe i can shed light on this.  This isn't doing anything other than letting the post install fail and then using the checked in (scm) version of the bower dependencies.  This is not using bower on the prod setup.  This is not even really a hack, it is a blatant misuse of how bower/heroku/builds are supposed to work

Comment: I would avoid committing bower_components (or any other third party stuff) to my repository, of course it's a matter of taste. Here's a short article on that matter: 
http://blog.silvabox.com/should-you-commit-bower-components-to-git/

Comment: I would never commit my bower directory in git under normal situation, but here I just needed a quick solution

Comment: ''npm install bower --save" will be the solution.
installing bower using npm will install bower first and install bower dependencies later(without any issue).
Adding all the bower installed libs is not a good practice i think. 
The above fix worked because, bower installed libs are forcibly pushed to heroku @reergymerej

Answer (score 12):

This is likely related to this issue with bower, the cause of which is currently still being investigated:

https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/933

I've also been having some similar issues with the `bower install` command failing on heroku. Here's what worked for me:

**1. Temporarily remove `node_modules` and `bower_components` from `.gitignore`.**

- This seemed to fix an `ENOENT` error when trying to install Angular using bower through a postinstall script in heroku.
- Note: If you specify a different installation directory for bower components in your `.bowerrc` file, then make sure that directory is *not* present in your `.gitignore`.

**2. Edit (or create) `.bowerrc` and tell it to use temp directories that are local to the project directory:**

```
{
    "storage": {
        "packages": ".bower-cache",
        "registry": ".bower-registry"
    },
    "tmp": ".bower-tmp"
}
```

- By default, bower was trying to use a directory in `/app`, which was resulting in `ENOTEMPTY` errors (maybe because it was trying to clear those directories, but it didn't have access because they are shared with other users? Just throwing out a guess...)
- Using a directory that's local to the project fixed the conflicts.

Hope this helps someone else.

**Note:** Even after performing the above steps, the `bower install` command may still occasionally fail.  However, it generally works the second or third time - just try running the command again... Until the underlying issue is resolved, that's the best advice that I can offer.

Comment: Adding Bower's cache/ temp folders to the `.gitignore` file fixed the `ENOTEMPTY` issue for me.

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue. The problem was that in the `bower.json` file:

```
{
    "name": "mean",
    "version": "0.1.3",
    "dependencies": {
        "angular": "1.2.8",
        "angular-resource": "latest",
        "angular-cookies": "latest",
        "angular-mocks": "latest",
        "angular-route": "latest",
        "bootstrap": "3.0.3",
        "angular-bootstrap": "0.10.0",
        "angular-ui-utils": "0.1.0"
    }
}
```

"bower install" is unable to determine the angular version and requires manual intervention to choose the right version:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for angular, please choose one:
    1) angular#1.2.8 which resolved to 1.2.8 and has mean as dependants
    2) angular#1.2.9 which resolved to 1.2.9 and has angular-cookies#1.2.9, angular-mocks#1.2.9, angular-resource#1.2.9, angular-route#1.2.9 as dependants
    3) angular#>= 1.0.2 which resolved to 1.2.10-build.2176+sha.e020916 and has angular-ui-utils#0.1.0 as dependants
    4) angular#>=1 which resolved to 1.2.10-build.2176+sha.e020916 and has angular-bootstrap#0.10.0 as dependants
Prefix the choice with ! to persist it to bower.json
[?] Answer:
```

So Heroku fails when it executes the script.

**FIX**

Just change the version of angular in your `bower.json` file:

```
"angular": "1.2.10",
```

`1.2.9` will also work.

Comment: Now that seems to make sense.  Heroku likely can't understand those additional messages.  I'll try this today!  Thanks ibeitia :)

Answer (score 4):

@ac360 This isn't an issue with bower at all.  It's generally a warning you can get if different libraries use the same dependency however a different version.   You should never add your `public/lib to the repo`.  That defeats the purpose of what bower can be used for.   Keep your repo as light as possible, and let dependencies download and resolve at build time so you can get the latest and greatest within the parameters defined in your `bower.json`

To resolve this issue completely for auto-deploys, bower gives us a property on the `bower.json` called `resolutions`

Simply create the following in your `bower.json`

```
"resolutions": {
  "ember": "1.2.10"
}
```

The reason you still had problems even if you had resolutions defined was because the version you picked wasn't going to satisfy all dependencies so the question came up during the heroku install.

Alternatively, you can build locally, and when you are asked which version to choose from, if you preceed the number choice with the bang `!` symbol, bower will update your bower.json for you!

See: https://github.com/bower/bower/issues/532

Answer (score 3):

I got it working by ensuring to save bower in package.json using the command below. The save will install bower using npm on server before attempting to run bower install

```
npm install bower --save
```

the postinstall script in package.json
"postinstall:"bower install" worked on heroku after that.

Comment: This is the apt solution

Comment: Yes. Worked like a charm